# How to insert emoticons in the chat box?

Tags: game-of-war-fire-age

I could't figure out how to insert emoticons in the chat box in Game of War.

I tried some of [these](http://fireage.wikia.com/wiki/MediaWiki:Emoticons) combinations, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the iOS version, this is the Emoji Keyboard.

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4976